# How to convert a ' ' to an int?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe with a column that is objects. When i check for null values the data set says it has no null values but there is one row thats has a ' ' for age.
I want to convert the column from object to int but that 1 value is giving me a hard time.

Here is what i have tried:

```
df['perpetrator_age'].replace('', '0', regex=True)
df.head()
```

Which does not replace the value.

```
df['perpetrator_age'].astype(int)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

After some searching i thought maybe try convert it to a float first but :

```
df['perpetrator_age'].astype(float).astype(int)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `df['perpetrator_age'].replace('', 0, regex=False)`? Please provide a reproducible example of input

Comment: or `df['perpetrator_age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['perpetrator_age'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)`?

Comment: `df['perpetrator_age']=df['perpetrator_age'].replace('', '0')`

Comment: Copy / paste error. Edited...

Comment: Did you assing the changes of the `replace()`-call? Maybe it is just a missing assignment and it was working all the time.

Comment: @mozway so the first code ran but did not replace the value, The second also ran. but as the dataframe says it has no NaN values it also did not work.

Comment: @Martha `replace` is **not in place**, you should assign the output.

Comment: the assignment was indeed missing! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, I guess the assingment is missing.

Here is a very basic example with an `''` string.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,'',4,5]})
df['a'].replace('',0, inplace=True)
# df['a'] = df['a'].replace('',0) as an equivilant
>>> df.head()
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  0
4  4
5  5
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the assignment was missing so it turns out a simple `inplace=True` solved all of my problems!

The code I had originally written was actually fine, but without the inplace parameter it was not actually changing/overwriting the existing dataframe as inplace=False is the default. As soon as i added the inplace=True, it changed!

https://jman4190.medium.com/explaining-the-inplace-parameter-for-beginners-5de7ffa18d2e
This article was very helpful in explaining.

```
df['perpetrator_age'].replace(' ', 0, regex=False, inplace=True)
```

This changed my ' ' value to a zero , and i then ran the following code to convert the entire column from object to int.

```
df['perpetrator_age'].astype(int)
```

Thank you everyone for your help :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added some more info :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
df['perpetrator_age'].astype('int')
```

Don't forget the ' '